# Filling an array in an outside method and returning count to main

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to write a code that will use the main to ask for the number of numbers the user wants, and then the user enters them. Then in an outside method, I need to get those numbers from the array and find the numbers that are both even, and bigger than 60. After that, I need to print both of those back into the main. Here is what I have:

```
public class arrayCounter
{//begin class
public static void main(String[]args)
{//begin main method
  java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println();

  double greaterThan = 0;
  double evenNumber = 0;

  System.out.println("Please enter the number of intergers you want to put into the array.");
  int numbers = input.nextInt();
  int[] arrayInt = new int[numbers];
  int i = 0;

  for (i =0; i < arrayInt.length; i++){//begin for loop
      System.out.println("Please enter in those numbers now.");
      arrayInt[i] = input.nextInt();
      }//end for loop

     System.out.println("There are  " + greaterThan + " numbers that are greater than 60.");
     System.out.println("The even numbers are " + evenNumber + " in the array.");
}//end main



public static double arrayCounter (double greaterThan, double evenNumber){//begins outside method
  int i = 0;
  int numbers = 0;
  int[] arrayInt = new int[numbers];
  for (i = 0; i < arrayInt.length; i++){//begins for loop
     if(arrayInt[i] <= 60){//begin if loop
     greaterThan++;
     return greaterThan;
    }//end if loop
  }//end for loop

     if(arrayInt[i] % 2 == 0){//begin if loop
     evenNumber++;
     return evenNumber;
  }//end if loop
   return 0;
 }//end outside method
}//end class
```

When I compile it in both NetBeans and Putty, It compiles just fine, but it doesn't actually give me any numbers in the answer, just 0. It will say:
"There are  0.0 numbers that are greater than 60.
The even numbers are 0.0 in the array."

What am I doing wrong to not get the proper numbers?

Comment: There are a few things wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are returning values one at a time in arrayCounter so you can't get both variables like this. I wonder if you are thinking it works like C/C++ using references/pointers? It doesn't work like that.

Instead declare your variables in your class to make them re-usable as a part of scope.

```java
public class arrayCounter  
{//begin class  
double greaterThan = 0.0;  
double evenNumber = 0.0;
```

Then class variables only need to be added/incremented in your arrayCounter method like you did below.

`greaterThan++; evenNumber++;`

Now that you are not trying to return values, let's get rid of the return statements, the input parameters, and change the return type from double to void as seen below.

`public static void arrayCounter () {`

Finally, in Main, you need to actually call your function before you reach your System.out lines.
`arrayCounter();`

There are still some improvements and error handling that you may need to do once those changes have been made but you are almost there.